# Get value from applied definition query and update field value

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0

I have a layer "ABC", in which I have a field [LABEL]. In the field [LABEL]  some feature have been filled with the value "TSL/VNR/DT8A"
    definition Query is already set to `[LABEL] ='TSL/VNR/DT8A'`

I now need a script that could read the content of the definition query, pull out the single quoted text and fill this value to other feature.

Below is the code I am preparing.

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd,"ABC")
# Getting Current Definition Query
DEFQUERY =  layers[0].definitionQuery

# Print DEQUERY
# [LABEL] ='TSL/VNR/DT8A'

***# challange is to extract single quoted text from entire definition query.***
SingleQuotedText = ***some expression to pull out single quoted text from DEFQUERY***

#releasing definition query.
lyrnm = arcpy.mapping.Layer("ABC")
lyrnm.definitionQuery = None

#cursor to update unique value in field LABEL
cursor = arcpy.UpdateCursor("ABC")
for row in cursor:
        row.LABEL = SingleQuotedText 
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

My challenge is to pull out the single quoted text and put it into the cursor.
I am not having good knowledge of regular expression. It may help me, but don't know how to apply it.

Comment: Extracting part of a string from another string is a pure Python question that should be researched, and asked (if necessary), on [so].  If you don't find the answer and need to ask there, I recommend you do not include any of the ArcPy parts of your question from here because they are irrelevant to what you would need to ask.  You already seem to have the ArcPy part sorted.

Comment: it was just a suggestion to use regular expression . if there is any other alternatives  to Solve my problem in arcpy. that is also very welcome.

Comment: There is nothing that I know of in ArcPy for string manipulation.

Comment: i am not talking about only string manipulation. i am talking about entire script.     i.e. pull out definition query text and use in update cursor.

Comment: You already have your first string stored in `DEFQUERY` and you are trying to get part of that into a second string `SingleQuotedText` - that's simply string manipulation and where you are stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by "single quoted text"?  Is that text different to `'TSL/VNR/DT8A'`?  Can you give an example please?

Comment: i need just TSL/VNR/DT8A